# FormValidation adding dynamic fields creating double bootstrap selects

Tags: bootstrap-select, formvalidation-plugin, bootstrapvalidator, formvalidation.io

I am using formValidation plugin and adding dynamic fields with it.

Right now, when I click add, the bootstrap-select is refreshed, but it keeps adding two of the select dropdown.

[image]

If somebody can point me in the right direction, would be helpful!

### JS

```
// Add work experience handler
            .on('click', '.addWork', function() {
            workindex++;
            var $template = $('#userWork'),
                $clone    = $template
            .clone()
            .removeClass('hide')
            .removeAttr('id')
            .appendTo($("#workAppendContainer"));

            // Update the name attributes
            $clone
                .find('[name="year"]').attr('name', 'userWorkDuration[]').end()
                .find('[name="worklocation"]').attr('name', 'userWorkLocation[]').end()
                .find('[name="workdescription"]').attr('name', 'userWorkDescription[]').end()
                .find('[name="workpositionname"]').attr('name', 'userWorkName[]').end();

            // Add new fields
            // Note that we also pass the validator rules for new field as the third parameter
            $('#rootwizard')
                .formValidation('addField', 'userWorkDuration[]')
                .formValidation('addField', 'userWorkLocation[]')
                .formValidation('addField', 'userWorkDescription[]')
                .formValidation('addField', 'userWorkName[]');

            $('.durationSelect').selectpicker('refresh');

        })
```

### Here is the template I am using to clone and the container

```
<div class="form-group hide" id="userWork">
        <div class="row" style="margin-top:15px;">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="col-md-6" style="padding-left: 0px;">
                      <label>Algus</label>
                        <div class="form-group form-group-custom">
                        <select class="durationSelect selectpicker" data-live-search="true"  name="year">
                          <optgroup class="userWorkYear">
                            <option disabled selected value="">
                                Vali kestvus
                            </option> 
                            <option value="-3">Vähem kui kolm kuud</option>  
                            <option value="3 kuud">3 kuud</option>
                            <option value="6 kuud">6 kuud</option>
                            <option value="9 kuud">9 kuud</option>
                            <option value="1 aasta">1 aasta</option>
                            <option value="2 aastat">2 aastat</option>
                            <option value="3 aastat">3 aastat</option>
                            <option value="3+">Rohkem kui 3 aastat</option>
                          </optgroup>
                        </select>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
   <div id="workAppendContainer">
    </div>
```

Comment: bootstrap-select initializing twice is the reason two of the select dropdown

Comment: okay so now I was able to destory the select instance and then refreshing it but now it gives me an error that please choose at least once choice even tho it is chosen. any suggestions @Shehary